# Slow down my javascript! How to allow my code to wait for transition to complete before executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, transition, optimization

Strange Question i guess but i have this bit of code in my page...

```
$(".map-overlay-left").click(function () {  
    $("#map-holder").hide('slow');                                  
    var gmarkers = [];
    var side_bar_html = "";

    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map-holder'));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    var Africa = new GLatLng(-2.767478,23.730469);
    map.setCenter(Africa, 4);   

    $.get("http://xx.xxx.xxxx.xxx/xml-feed-google-maps",{},function(xml) {
        $('marker',xml).each(function(i) {
            html = $(this).text();
            lat = $(this).attr("lat");
            lng = $(this).attr("lng");
            label = $(this).attr("label");
            var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
            var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
        });
    });

    $("#map-holder").show('slow');
});
```

This works fantasticly and does what i want functionally just not UI wise.  It's meant to first do a nice transition to hide the div "map-holder", render the google map inside it, then do a nice transition back to size.  The transition is the default JQuery show/hide.

Now the problem i seem to be getting is that the Google Map is being rendered while this `$("#map-holder").hide('slow');` is still running and you see a glimps of the map before it hides, and then opens up again, which kinda defies the whole effect.

Thus anyone have any idea how i can slow the code down to wait for the hide function to finish before doing the rest? ( ideally i don't want to use something hard coded in like setTimeout).

Thanks in advance!

Shadi

**UPDATE 1**

I've placing a call back on the hide function but it has a very strange effect on GMap.  In Chrome/FF/Safari it then only renders a small segment in the corner of the map when it shows up. and in IE it is completely thrown off and centers on a different location.  the GMap seems not to like being rendered in a hidden div.

You can see it here http://afid.staging.dante-studios.com/ it's on the front (just hit the play button on Asia or Africa to see the weird effect).

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

**UPDATE 2**
Attempted to fix the Google Map issue of not rendering correctly in a hidden div with this:

```
$(".map-overlay-left").click(function () {  
    $("#map-holder").hide('slow', function(){                                   
        var gmarkers = [];
        var side_bar_html = "";

        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map-holder'));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        var Africa = new GLatLng(-2.767478,23.730469);
        map.setCenter(Africa, 4);   

        $.get("http://afid.staging.dante-studios.com/xml-feed-google-maps",{},function(xml) {
            $('marker',xml).each(function(i) {
                html = $(this).text();
                lat = $(this).attr("lat");
                lng = $(this).attr("lng");
                label = $(this).attr("label");
                var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
                var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);
                map.addOverlay(marker);
            });
        });

    });
    $("#map-holder").show('slow');
    map.checkResize();
    map.setCenter(Africa, 4);   
});
```

But alas no luck with the `map.checkResize();` method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [callback to `.hide`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/hide#speedcallback) to perform your work after the animation is complete:

```
$("#map-holder").hide('slow', function() {
  var gmarkers = [];
  var side_bar_html = "";      

  // ...

  $("#map-holder").show('slow');
})
```

Comment: I've updated the question regarding the issue created by the callback fix...any ideas? :)

Comment: shadi: try moving `var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map-holder'))` to just before the call to `hide()`. What does that do?

Comment: @Roatin: Perfect it fixed it, i guess getting that in made gmap understand the container before it went poof! - Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a callback function to the hide function, which will run when it is done hiding it:

```
$(".map-overlay-left").click(function () {      
    $("#map-holder").hide('slow', function(){                                                                  
        var gmarkers = [];
        var side_bar_html = "";

        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map-holder'));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        var Africa = new GLatLng(-2.767478,23.730469);
        map.setCenter(Africa, 4);       

        $.get("http://afid.staging.dante-studios.com/xml-feed-google-maps",{},function(xml) {
            $('marker',xml).each(function(i) {
                html = $(this).text();
                lat = $(this).attr("lat");
                lng = $(this).attr("lng");
                label = $(this).attr("label");
                var point = new GLatLng(lat,lng);
                var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);
                map.addOverlay(marker);
                //alert(lat + " " + lng + " " + label);
            });
        });

        $("#map-holder").show('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9090128/973578) SO answer if you're looking for vanilla JS.

The transition listner events vary in each browser, so the below function will find which listener to use and return the correct one.

```
function whichTransitionEvent(){
    var t;
    var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
    var transitions = {
      'transition':'transitionend',
      'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition':'transitionend',
      'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
    }

    for(t in transitions){
        if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
            return transitions[t];
        }
    }
}

var transitionEnd = whichTransitionEvent();
element.addEventListener(transitionEnd, theFunctionToInvoke, false);

function theFunctionToInvoke(){
// set margin of div here
}
```