# jQuery: wait for css animation to complete before changing another css attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a stack of images, absolutely positioned on the same place and I only have one image visible at a time by setting zIndex=-1 for all images but the visible one. On another side of the page I have a list of all the image names and when I hover on a specific image name I want that image to become visible by fading in and the previously visible one to fade out. I do this with this code

```
$(this).hover(  //visible and hover below are variable names  
        visible.css({opacity: '0',zIndex: '-1'}); //the previous image diassapears
        hovered.css({ zIndex: '1', opacity: '1'}); //the new image fades in
    )
```

and by transitioning the opacity property through css.
The problem is that when I hover over a new image name, the old image just disappears without fading out and the new one starts to fade in. I suppose that the old image does indeed fade out, yet it does so in the background due to zIndex=-1 becoming immediately effective. I would like to ask the best way to solve this. Please, notice that I want to do this without using jQuery animations and only using pure css animations just to take advantage of the (minimally) higher speed of css animations. So a solution that puts almost no computational overhead (so that a css animation in this case still remains advantageous) would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `z-index:-1` after it has animated back to opacity 0, otherwise it is just "popping" below without showing the opacity change.

You need to trigger on a transitionEnd event. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023514/how-do-i-normalize-css3-transition-functions-across-browsers) about normalizing that event for all browsers.

But once you work that out, its basically just attaching a one off event with the callback setting the final z-index - something like this:

```
visible.one('transitionEnd', function(){
    visible.css('z-index', -1);
}).css( 'opacity', 0 );
```

You just need to use the script in the other SO post to get your normalized `'transitionEnd'` event.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great. But what about any computational burden? Does this method still renders css transitions faster than jQuery animations?

Comment: Well, by running a css transition, the animation is now hardware accelerated - so that it looks better. And I think they look a lot better. I have not specifically run into performance issues with this method, it really should be better than just doing a jQuery animation because a jQuery animation is just setting the css of opacity a bunch of times to make it animate - css transition is handled by the browser itself, making it more smooth.

Comment: I guess a better question is are you (or your client) going to be upset if your animations do not work in ie7 and 8. If that is a problem, you either need to use jquery animation or look into further polyfills - i have seen some that will fill with a setTimeout to run the transition callback if you are on an old browser that does not support transition events.

Answer (score 0):

use `animate` - it comes with queue management and callback support "out of the box"

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I think animate() uses jQuery animations, no? I want to use native css transitions.