# CSS3 Smooth transition when dynamically changing animations

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, html5-animation

I have two keyframe animations "Bounce-In" and "Bounce-Out" the Bounce-In animation takes 1.2 seconds to complete, but if a user triggers the Bounce-Out function before it's finished it will jump to 100% scale and doesn't gracefully scale out from it's current animation position.

Is this possible with keyframe animations? I've seen it done with transition property but not using scale().

```
@-webkit-keyframes Bounce-In 
{
0% { -webkit-transform: scale(0) }
40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }
60% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.7) }
80% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }
90% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.9) }
100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }
}

@-webkit-keyframes Bounce-Out 
{
0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }
40% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.1) }
60% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.4) }
80% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.1) }
90% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.2) }
100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0) }
}
```

I have a demo on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vn3bM/98/
*if you click the "Games" circle before the animation is finished you will notice the other two jump to 100% and then animate out (that's what I'm trying to make smooth).

I even tried removing the 0% keyframe from Bounce-Out and that didn't help...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your case, the "jump" you notice in your animation comes from the change of animations you have installed on onmouseup. The "Bounce-Out" Animation has an initial scale of 1 (first Keyframe), and this is what the two circles immediately get set to when the animation is installed.

There are two solutions to this, which I can explain in some detail:

### The Easy Way

You could just wait for the initial animation to end via the 'webkitAnimationEnd' Event and install the onmouseup event with a recursive function waiting for the animation to finish:

```
var initAnimationEnded = false;
document.getElementById('sports').addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
 initAnimationEnded = true;
}, false);​
```

And here's the onmouseup handler:

```
document.getElementById('games').onmouseup = function() {
  function bounceOut() {
    if (initAnimationEnded) {
        events.style.webkitAnimationName = "Bounce-Out";
        sports.style.webkitAnimationDelay = "0.2s";
        sports.style.webkitAnimationName = "Bounce-Out";
    } else {
        setTimeout(bounceOut, 20);
    }
  }
  bounceOut();
}
```

I installed a **[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GPMta/)** so you can see it working. The Bounce Out animation is only triggered after the animation finished, nothing unusual about that.

### The Hard Way

You can pause the animation and parse the current values of the transformation, then install a temporary keyframe animation to bounce out. This gets much more verbose though:

First, you have to stop the animations:

```
events.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
sports.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
```

Then, you set up a helper to insert new css rules:

```
var addCssRule = function(rule) {
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.innerHTML = rule;
  document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

Then create the css keyframe rules on the fly and insert them:

```
    // get the current transform scale of sports and events

    function getCurrentScaleValue(elem) {
      return document.defaultView.
      getComputedStyle(elem, null).
      getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform').
      match(/matrix\(([\d.]+)/)[1];
    }

    var currentSportsScale = getCurrentScaleValue(sports);
    var currentEventsScale = getCurrentScaleValue(events);

     // set up the first string for the keyframes rule

    var sportsTempAnimation = ['@-webkit-keyframes Sports-Temp-Bounce-Out {'];
    var eventsTempAnimation = ['@-webkit-keyframes Events-Temp-Bounce-Out {'];

     // basic bounce out animation

    var bounceOutAnimationBase = {
        '0%': 1,
        '40%': 0.1,
        '60%': 0.4,
        '80%': 0.1,
        '90%': 0.2,
        '100%': 0
    };

     // scale the animation to the current values

    for (prop in bounceOutAnimationBase) {
        sportsTempAnimation.push([
          prop, ' 
          { -webkit-transform: scale(', 
          currentSportsScale * bounceOutAnimationBase[prop], 
          ') } '].join(''));
        eventsTempAnimation.push([
           prop, 
           ' { -webkit-transform: scale(', 
           currentEventsScale * bounceOutAnimationBase[prop], 
           ') } '
         ].join(''));
    }

     // add closing brackets

    sportsTempAnimation.push('}');
    eventsTempAnimation.push('}');

     // add the animations to the rules

    addCssRule([sportsTempAnimation.join(''), 
                eventsTempAnimation.join('')].join(' '));
```

Then, you restart the animations with these rules:

```
    events.style.webkitAnimationName = "Events-Temp-Bounce-Out";
    events.style.webkitAnimationDelay = "0s";
    sports.style.webkitAnimationDelay = "0s";
    sports.style.webkitAnimationName = "Sports-Temp-Bounce-Out";
    events.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
    sports.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
```

Et voilà. I made a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stJFd/)** here so you can play around with it.

### More Sugar

- **In your example, the circles bounce out alternating in bounce**. You can easily get this back to work with the second solution by using setTimeout for all sports circle animations. I did not want to include it here because it would unnecessarily complicate the example code.
- **I know the provided examples are not really DRY**, you could for example make all the stuff for events and sports work with half the lines of code (with meta properties), but in terms of readability, I think this example serves well.
- **To have this example working in all browsers with support for css3 animations**, you need to normalize the transition properties. To do this in javascript, [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023514/how-do-i-normalize-css3-transition-functions-across-browsers) The Example works for animations and other properties as well, just replace 'transition' with the property you want
- **For a further read on modifying css3 animations on the fly**, I found [this post](http://blog.joelambert.co.uk/2011/09/07/accessing-modifying-css3-animations-with-javascript/) very useful, have a look at it as well.