# Adding transition to show-hide menu

Tags: javascript, transition, show-hide

I have a fairly simple menu that works as intended, but I just don't know how to add a transition to it so it will look smoother. Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showhide(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    e.style.transition = "all 1s";
 }
</script>


<a href="javascript:showhide('SERIES')">
    <div class="search-menu-maincategory">
        Maincategory to click on
    </div>
</a>

<div id="SERIES">
    <div class="search-menu-subcategory">
        One of the subcategories to show and hide
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously the e.style.transition = "all 1s"; part is not what I need since it is not working. How can I add a one second transition between the show and hide? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transition.asp

Comment: I came up with the e.style.transition when I saw that link, but that is not working or am I misinterpreting it?

Answer (score 1):

Two things: you can't transition on a display property, use visibility and opacity instead.

`#foo {
    transition-property: visibility, opacity;
    transition-duration: 0, 1s;
}`

`#foo.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition-property: opacity, visibility;
    transition-duration: 1s, 0;
    transition-delay: 0, 1s;
}`

I suggest using css class names to control showing/hiding otherwise you will have to write a function that uses the request animation frame function to redraw the window so the animation actually shows up otherwise you wont have a transition https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `height: 0` should fix your block problem

```js
function showhide(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.classList.toggle("m-fadeOut");
 }
```

```css
.m-fadeOut {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 300ms, opacity 300ms, height 300ms;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:showhide('SERIES')">
    <div class="search-menu-maincategory">
        Maincategory to click on
    </div>
</a>

<div id="SERIES">
    <div class="search-menu-subcategory">
        One of the subcategories to show and hide
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising, but can it be done with `display:none` aswell? `visibility:hidden` leaves space even if the menu is supposed to be collapsed.

Comment: set the height to 0 as well I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: The transitions work for visibility and opacity, but height gets instantly reduced to 0 without transition?! Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: the problem is javascript is setting the height to 0 before the css transition finishes, take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15618028