# Why does this callback not unbind itself to transitionEnd after completing one animation?

Tags: jquery, css, callback, css-transitions, addclass

hi im trying to bind a function to webkitTransitionEnd using jquery's .one method. when i do:

```
$element.one( "transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd",
function(e) { 
    $element.removeClass( ".alert-resets" ) 
 });
```

it doesn't unbind to the transitionend event. instead it removes the class every time it does the transition

heres the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DVC5A/

ok i found this solution on SO:

[How do I normalize CSS3 Transition functions across browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023514/how-do-i-normalize-css3-transition-functions-across-browsers)

Comment: The docs for .one() explicitly state: "If the first argument contains more than one space-separated event types, the event handler is called once for each event type.". Look at the console here: http://jsfiddle.net/DVC5A/2/

Comment: how can i overcome this then?

Comment: can you post this as answer with a possible solution, so i can mark it as the answer

Comment: i tested it in jsfiddle, and that seems to be the case. i used just one event name, and it worked fine.

Comment: how can i use all possible vendor prefixes and just bind to one event?

Comment: ok i found this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023514/how-do-i-normalize-css3-transition-functions-across-browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs for .one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) explicitly state: "If the first argument contains more than one space-separated event types, the event handler is called once for each event type.".

I don't know if there is a more proper way to deal with this type of event (listening for only one event name would probably work but I donno how that'd work cross-browser). But in any case you can just unbind it yourself with .off(), and you can use an event namespace to make that easier:

```
$(".my_butt").on("click", function (e) {
    $(".block").addClass("in");

    $(".block").on("transitionend.my MSTransitionEnd.my webkitTransitionEnd.my oTransitionEnd.my", function (e) {
        var el = $(this);
        el.off('.my');
        setTimeout(function () {
            el.removeClass("in");
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DVC5A/6/

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023514/how-do-i-normalize-css3-transition-functions-across-browsers

Answer (score 4):

Don't use **one()**... use **on()** (like normal) and then unbind your event handler with **off()** at the end of your transition end event handler

```
$("#button-element").on('click', function(e){
    var transEnd = 
        "transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd";

    // ... trigger your css3 transition
    $('#el').addClass('whatever');

    // then ...
    $('#el').on(transEnd, function (e) {
        // do stuff
        $('#el').removeClass('whatever');

        //unbind event handler
        $('#el').off(transEnd);

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't get what you're trying to do, but I'll try anyway? This is your code:

```
$(".my_butt").on("click", function (e) {
    $(".block").addClass("in");

    $(".block").one("transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd", function (e) {
        console.log('pl')
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".block").removeClass("in");
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

So everytime you click the button you rebind the `transitionEnd` event for `one()` more time as the event handler is inside the click event handler for the button, so of course it removes the class everytime you click the button?

To attach the `transitionEnd` event handler just one time for each time the document loads, just move the event handler out of the click function for the button ?

```
$(".my_butt").on("click", function (e) {
    $(".block").addClass("in");
});

$(".block").one("transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd", function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".block").removeClass("in");
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: yea, sorry for the brain fart, thats right, thats what i wanted to do, thank you.