# promise().done() method is not waiting until my animate.css effect has finished

Tags: jquery, html, css, window

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew3LV/).

As you can see, I'm trying to open google.com in the same window AFTER the big red ball has finished fading in from right. Instead, google.com opens about a second after the fade in from right starts. How do I get my window.location function to wait until the fade in completely finishes?

Yes, I have JQuery 1.6.2 linked to my page.

Markup:

```
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><img class="animated fadeInRightBig" src="http://www.clipartsfree.net/vector/large/roystonlodge_Simple_Glossy_Circle_Button_Red_Vector_Clipart.png" style="">
     </a>
</body>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.animated').promise().done(function(){
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
});
```

Vincent: I tried the following, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

```
$('.animated fadeInRightBig').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd     otransitionend', function() {
window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
});
```

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I assume `deferred` only works with jQuery animations, not css transitions.

Comment: You want to add a queue function to the 'fx' queue (which is default) on your `.animated` element which does your redirect. that queue function will be automatically called when the transition/animation is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an easier way using meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="6; url=https://www.google.com/">
<meta name="keywords" content="automatic redirection">
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a callback handler like this...

---

`$("#someElement").show('slide', {}, 400, function(){//your code here!});`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `promise().done` applies to CSS transistions. Try using the transitionEnd event.

This is different across browsers, so you should look at this:

[How do I normalize CSS3 Transition functions across browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023514/how-do-i-normalize-css3-transition-functions-across-browsers)

E.g.

```
$('.animated').bind('transitionEnd', function() {
    window.location = 'bla';
});
```

Comment: I realized this later and agree. I tried the transitionEnd with Firefox and from what I read, this should work. Instead, no redirect.

Comment: $('.animated fadeInRightBig').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd     otransitionend', function() {
window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
});

Comment: No, not even the quick redirect.

Comment: Got this from a friend and it worked! <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="6; url=https://www.google.com/">
 meta name="keywords" content="automatic redirection">

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a queue function to the 'fx' queue (which is default) on your `.animated` element which does your redirect. that queue function will be automatically called when the transition/animation is finished.

```
$('.animated').queue('fx', function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location = url;
});

// this will dequeue your added function automatically
$('.animated').addClass('fadeInRightBig');
```

Comment: Use some imagination and maybe setTimeout and you'll get there. You can also try to leverage the .delay() function.

Comment: This was much easier. Got this from a non-stack friend. <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="6; url=https://www.google.com/">
 meta name="keywords" content="automatic redirection">

Answer (score 0):

You should use this flag :

```
animation_end = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend";
```

This worked for me :

```
animation_end = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend";

remove_hallway = function(){
    var hallway = $("#hallway_wrapper");
    hallway.addClass("animated");
    hallway.addClass("zoomOutUp");
    hallway.one(animation_end,function(){
        hallway.css("visibility","hidden");
        hallway.removeClass("zoomOutUp");
        hallway.removeClass("animated");
        $("#room_wrapper").css("visibility","visible");
        create_room(["Default",urls],"fadeInUp");
});
```

This code has worked for me. It will execute what's inside hallyway.one() only when the zoomOutUp animation that was invoked right before it finishes.