# How can I create a custom event to handle all transitionend events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, transition, event-listener, custom-events

I want to create a custom event that handles all the different vendor-prefixed versions of the `transitionend` event (i.e., `webkitTransitionEnd`, `mozTransitionEnd`, `msTransitionEnd`, `oTransitionEnd` and the W3C `transitionend` event).

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use the custom `transitionend` event I want to create as follows:

```
elem.addEventListener('myTransitionEnd', function (evt) {
  // Called whenever any transitionend event fires.
});
```

Unfortunately, I have no clue how to do this. I was looking into `document.createEvent`, but I couldn't figure out how to use `document.createEvent` with `initEvent` and `dispatchEvent` to actually get my custom `transitionend` event to fire when any applicable `transitionend` event fires for some arbitrary DOM elements that I set up with my custom event at a later time.

Any help with the code would be greatly appreciate.
In addition, if there is a better approach to this problem than creating a custom event, please let me know.
In the end, I really just want to have a solution that is as modular as possible (and I was hoping to learn a thing or two about custom events in JS while I'm at it).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023514/how-do-i-normalize-css3-transition-functions-across-browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be creating a global variable (string) with all transitionend events in it. And then add a eventlistener to that string. Example:

```
//your global var:
window.endTransition = 'webkitTransitionEnd mozTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd transitionend';

//your event
elem.addEventListener(window.endTransition, function(e){
    //your awesome piece of JS
});
```

Comment: Ah, cool. I didn't know that could be done. That may in fact be the easiest/best solution, but before I mark it as the correct answer, I would like to know how to go the custom event route as well, just for the sake of learning.

Comment: This is a good solution. Thank you. I actually ended up going with the Modernizr way of doing things though, which is noted in the link in the comment to my question. I went that route because I was concerned about some edge cases where more than one event might fire when you set up an event handler for all the different versions of transitionend. Thanks again, though.

Comment: Modernizr is indeed a better solution for more complicated applications. My solution is pretty much the easiest way to go.