# Direction Aware 3D Cube Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, 3d

I've built some 3D cube hover animations which are direction aware, using this direction function:

```
var getDirection = function (ev, obj) {
var w = obj.offsetWidth,
    h = obj.offsetHeight,
    x = (ev.pageX - obj.offsetLeft - (w / 2) * (w > h ? (h / w) : 1)),
    y = (ev.pageY - obj.offsetTop - (h / 2) * (h > w ? (w / h) : 1)),
    d = Math.round( Math.atan2(y, x) / 1.57079633 + 5 ) % 4;

return d;};
```

see fiddle:
[JSFidde](http://jsfiddle.net/Ygku2/)

Problem I'm having is that the 'out' animation starts wether the 'in' animation has finished or not.

So I need a way of on mouseout waiting for the mousein animation to finish first, I assume using animation queueing or something.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did this only with CSS: http://dropthebit.com/793/3d-hover-aware-cube/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, I just used active and animating classes.

Mouse on adds active class / direction attr.
Mouse of removes active class / direction attr.

If object has animating class when hovered off/on return false, if object doesn't have active class when animation finishes play close animation.

Thanks for your help tho!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can listen to

```
 transitionEnd
```

event?

this SO post can get that normalized

[How do I normalize CSS3 Transition functions across browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023514/how-do-i-normalize-css3-transition-functions-across-browsers)