# Native like navigation using css and js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/q1a4wwar/7/

I want to do like native feel kind of navigation using web css. But I stuck at bringing back my .content slide back to the left. Try click on the item and then click on the back, you will notice my problem there.

```js
$(function(){
    $('.item').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('slideLeftItem');
        $('.content').show(0,'', function(){
            $('#back').show();
        }).addClass('slideRightContent');
    });
    
    $('#back').on('click',function(){
        
        $('.item').show().removeClass('slideLeftItem');
        $(this).hide();
        $('.content').hide().removeClass('slideRightContent');
    });
});
```

```css
.content{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
right: -200px;
top: 0px;
background: blue;
transition: 0.4s;
}

.item{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0px;
transition: 0.4s;
}

.slideRightContent{
    right: 0px;
}


.slideLeftItem{
    left: -200px;
}

#back{
    display:none;
    height: 20px !Important;
    background: grey !Important;

}

.content, .item{
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}

.phone{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s;
   width:200px;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="back">< back</div>


<br>
<div class="phone">
    
<div class="item">item</div>
<div class="content">My content</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: It is not very clear, what do you exactly mean by "native like". E.g. there are multiple approaches to easing -in or -out the animations. Do you have a device or web UI experience in mind that you want to replicate. If so, please update your question.

Comment: @AlexPakka try to click the result up there, u didn't notice something is missing?

Comment: there is a white thing there when u click back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hiding the `.content` div before the css transition has time to complete.

remove `.hide()` from the `#back` click method.

```
$('.content').removeClass('slideRightContent');
```

then bind to the css transition end event to hide the `.content` div for only the back event. We will use `.once` for this. IF you end up doing multi level/depth "slides" you may instead want to use `.on` and then `.off` each time.

```
$('.content').removeClass('slideRightContent').once('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', 
    function() {
         $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q1a4wwar/10/)**

Comment: do I really need these transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd ??

Comment: it is for cross browser compatibility.. as not all browsers trigger the same css transition end event.. see this answer that quotes modernizr's event listening http://stackoverflow.com/a/9090128/648350