# Javascript CSS Transitions to display:none work around?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

When animating an element to disappear with `opacity: 0`, then setting the display property to 'none' to remove it from view, `display:none` gets executed instantly, is there anyway to wait for the animation to complete before removing it from view with `display:none`

Here is the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/zg3q7jLt/38/

```
var box = document.querySelector('#box');

function addCssTransition(elem, speed) {
                elem.style.cssText +=
                    ';transition: all ' + speed + 's ease-in-out; ' +
                    '-moz-transition: all ' + speed + 's ease-in-out;' +
                    '-webkit-transition: all ' + speed + 's ease-in-out';
}

function fadeOut(elem, speed){
        addCssTransition(elem, speed);
        elem.style.opacity = 0;
        elem.style.display = 'none';
}

fadeOut(box, 0.75);
```

Comment: No jQuery please, this is not necessary for 12 lines of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen for transition-end events, but that's [problematic and in flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023514/how-do-i-normalize-css3-transition-functions-across-browsers) at the moment.

Your safest bet is probably a `setTimeout()`:

```
function fadeOut(elem, speed){
  addCssTransition(elem, speed);
  elem.style.opacity = 0;

  setTimeout( function() { elem.style.display = 'none'; }, speed * 1000 );
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why the 1000ms? is that the correct amount to calculate the fading?

Comment: You're passing `speed` in seconds (as appropriate for transitions). `setTimeout()` takes milliseconds. Multiplying by 1000 matches things up.

Answer (score 0):

Display: none doesn't have a transition because you can't partially display.

You can setTimeout like this:

```
var box = document.querySelector('#box');

function addCssTransition(elem, speed) {
                elem.style.cssText +=
                    ';transition: all ' + speed + 's ease-in-out; ' +
                    '-moz-transition: all ' + speed + 's ease-in-out;' +
                    '-webkit-transition: all ' + speed + 's ease-in-out';

setTimeout(function(){ 
 elem.style.cssText +=
                    ';display:none';

}, speed);
}

function fadeOut(elem, speed){
        addCssTransition(elem, speed);
        elem.style.opacity = 0;
        elem.style.display = 'none';
}

fadeOut(box, 0.75);
```